# VsCode - Update .njsproj

Tags: visual-studio-code

While working for a js project on `vs code` and `vs 2019` synchronously. Is there any way to update `.njsproj` automaticly file when adding a new folder and file on `vs code`? Thus, those files can be include solution explorer for `vs 2019` without manuel selecting files.

**Update**:

**I created an extension to sync .njsproj file on vs code automatically.**

[Vs Code .njsproj Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BerkanSivri.vscode-njsproj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code does not have built-in support for synchronizing Visual Studio project files.

You could try:

- An extension could provided this feature. [This one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jRichardeau.vscode-vsproj) claims it can, but I have not tested it
- Write a simple script that updates your njsproj based on current folder contents.
- If you are only using the project to open a set of files in VS, switch to use `open folder as workspace` instead.